# how to do Json parse for send messge in android

Tags: android

```
public String sendMsg(String message) throws IOException, JSONException {

    try {

         sendmsgurl = "http://api.lociiapp.com/api/message/sendmessage?member_id="

                + 452

                + "&to_id="

                + 452

                + "&message="

                + "Travell Request"

                + "&Notificationtype="
                + "1"

                + "&notificationId="
                + "50011"
                + "&notify_status="
                + "false";
        ;

        Log.e("Valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee", sendmsgurl);

        System.out.println("Valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee" + sendmsgurl);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return jsonResp;

}


private String getResult(String response) {

    String test = "";

    try {

        test=JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(sendmsgurl);
        JSONObject _jobj = new JSONObject(test);

        test = _jobj.getString("responseCode");

    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }

    return test;

}

public class sendMesgTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    String msg = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            String result = sendMsg(params[0]);

            msg = getResult(result);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (msg.equals("1")) {

        } else {

        }

    }

}
```

and calling method like this in On create :

```
new sendMesgTask().execute(Sendername
                        + ": Request For Travlling to You");
```

below is Json funcation Code:

```
public static String getJSONfromURL(String url){
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;


    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
            httppost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json;q=0.9,/;q=0.8");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

  //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    try{

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

When try to run this code then i am getting Exception and not getting repose code 
and exception i am getting below is the Error:

**Log-cat :**

1. >     09-11 11:32:48.805: E/Valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee(15432):

> http://api.lociiapp.com/api/message/sendmessage?member_id=453&to_id=454&message=Travell
>   Request&Notificationtype=1&notificationId=50011&notify_status=false
>       09-11 11:32:48.805: I/System.out(15432): Valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeehttp://api.lociiapp.com/api/message/sendmessage?member_id=453&to_id=454&message=Travell
>   Request&Notificationtype=1&notificationId=50011&notify_status=false
>       09-11 11:32:48.805: E/log_tag(15432): Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at
>   index 87:
>   http://api.lociiapp.com/api/message/sendmessage?member_id=453&to_id=454&message=Travell
>   Request&Notificationtype=1&notificationId=50011&notify_status=false
>       09-11 11:32:48.805: E/log_tag(15432): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
>       09-11 11:32:48.805: E/log_tag(15432): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: The error tells all. You have an illegal character in your query params. At 87.

Comment: http://api.lociiapp.com/api/message/sendmessage?member_id=453&to_id=454&message=Travell Request&Notificationtype=1&notificationId=50011&notify_status=false  see this work fine  when i Put in Broser

Comment: Yes. Because the browser knows how to send spaces. It wil url encode the string before sending. All spaces will be replaced by %20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space character in your url parameters. The space in 'Travel Request". Use URLEncoder.encode() before.

Comment: still same issue i have added  test=JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(Uri.encode(sendmsgurl));
   JSONObject _jobj = new JSONObject(test);

Comment: please tell how to Encode or how replace spacing please suggest

Comment: just use yoururl.replaceAll(" ","%20");

Comment: test=JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URLEncoder.encode(sendmsgurl));

Comment: and this  Error is coming he method encode(String) from the type URLEncoder is deprecated

Comment: Just show the complete url before and after using URLEncoder.encode(). Don't show me any json please as this has nothing to do with json. It is not relevant either how you build up that url.

Comment: i have applied that Logic and new Exception come now http://paste.ofcode.org/BpcBfhNCr8rZpY4SVy2HjQ

Comment: Please supply what i asked for.

Comment: 09-11 12:00:16.860: E/Valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee(29710): http://api.lociiapp.com/api/message/sendmessage?member_id=453&to_id=406&message=Travell Request&Notificationtype=1&notificationId=50011&notify_status=false

Comment: As you can see that is unreadable in a browser. Please remove the http from the url.

Comment: its working in Browser can u simply  tell me how to parse http://api.lociiapp.com/api/message/sendmessage?member_id=452&to_id=452&message=Travell%20Request&Notificationtype=1&notificationId=50011&notify_status=false  if pass messge from metod

Comment: You are not providing the info i asked for.